# Getting error while creating PL SQL function

Tags: plsql

Question is :
Create a Function named 'credit_limit' which takes shipment entity id(i.e, entity_id) as input and returns the  limit_status of type varchar. 
Function name : credit_limit 
Input Parameter : entity_id in int 
Output variable : limit_status variable of type varchar

**Design rules:** 
     1. If the credit_limit of the given entity id is greater then 50000,then display the limit_status as 'Credit limit is greater than 50000' 
     2. If the credit_limit of the given entity id is less then 50000,then display the limit_status as 'Credit limit is less than 50000' 
Note: DO NOT CHANGE the given status message in your solution.

```
create or replace function credit_limit (entity_id in integer)
return varchar
is
c_credit_limit NUMBER(*,2);
limit_status varchar(255);
begin
select credit_limit into c_credit_limit from shipment_entity 
where id = entity_id;
return(c_credit_limit);
if c_credit_limit > 50000 then
limit_status := 'Credit limit is greater than 50000';
else
if c_credit_limit < 50000 then
limit_status := 'Credit limit is less than 50000';
end if;
return (limit_status);
end;
/
```

I entered the code received an error

> Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

please help me out.

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Answer (score 0):

You get issue because of 2 reasons:

1) You can `return` only once from a `Function`. You used it `multiple` times.

2) `END IF` is missing in one of the `IF-ENDIF` block.

Modifed code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION credit_limit (entity_id IN INTEGER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   c_credit_limit   NUMBER (5, 2);
   limit_status     VARCHAR (255);
BEGIN
   SELECT credit_limit
     INTO c_credit_limit
     FROM shipment_entity
    WHERE id = entity_id;

   IF c_credit_limit > 50000
   THEN
      limit_status := 'Credit limit is greater than 50000';
   ELSE
      IF c_credit_limit < 50000
      THEN
         limit_status := 'Credit limit is less than 50000';
      END IF;
   END IF;

   RETURN (c_credit_limit);
END;
/
```